# Flann compiling error

Tags: c++, flann

I have an error compiling FLANN library, here it is:
error C2228: left of '.serialize' must have class/struct/union  C:\FLANN\libraries\flann-1.8.4-src\flann-1.8.4-src\src\cpp\flann\util\serialization.h

Here is a picture of all my configurations to compile FLANN, please help me.
The ALL_BUILD project generates the flann_cpp_s.lib, but no the flann.lib

[image]

Thks in advance!!!

Comment: You're not alone : https://github.com/chambbj/osgeo-superbuild/issues/3 just try to search a little for a quick fix.

Comment: This solution worked for me, thks a lot, I was searching for a solution to this in google, but I was not finding nothing useful. Thks to you!!!

Comment: I've made it an answer. Nice to know that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug is known.

See [here](https://github.com/chambbj/osgeo-superbuild/issues/3) for more details.